# Download build artifacts task not downloading to correct directory - downloads to the root of the drop directory and not drop/projectname

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Specified drop/projectname

[image]

it is downloading artifacts to the root of the drop directory. I need it to download to drop/projectname

[image]

The following task fails because it cannot find any files at drop/projectname, because it doesn't exist

[image]

Sort of new to this, but I've compared it to another application's pipeline which is identical and doesn't run into this issue.

Comment: Share how your pipeline is configured.

Comment: @DanielMann Where exactly? Like the CI/CD script? This is my first CI/CD task so please pardon my ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to change the output dir in my `angular-cli.json`. It was pointed at the `/dist` when it should have been `/dist/projectname`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept your answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear where you are trying to use the download task. In the release pipeline or build pipeline (classic or yaml)? Anyway, the [download task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) copies files to the downloadPath + artifact_name (drop by defualt).

In your case, you may just update your variable `PackageSubPath` to `drop` value or update your build source pipeline to copy files into the correct destination before publishing the artifact.

Comment: I'm using the download task in the release pipeline.

Changing the PackageSubPath to drop is plausible, I'm just trying to replicate other pipelines we have as much as possible - all of which are configured in the same exact way but download artifacts to drop/projectname